# Truncating of digits

Tags: c++

I was going through the following code. It basically truncates the the digits of the character entered through *cin* object. The problem is I don't know how assigning an int value to a character object truncates the digits except for the first.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    unsigned int integer;
    unsigned char character;
    cin >> integer;
    character = integer;
    cout << character ;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is I don't know how assigning an int value to a character object truncates the digits except for the first.

Let's for the sake of illustration assume that `char` is unsigned and is 8 bits wide, and `int` is 32 bits wide. What such an assignment would do is chop off the top 24 bits, leaving the bottom 8.

The truncation does not have anything to do with the *decimal* digits of the integer. For example, `9999` would become `15` (because `9999 & 0xFF == 15`).

Comment: Actually, "If the destination type is signed, [...] the value is implementation-defined.". Bear in mind that `char` *may* be a signed type.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I was expecting a comment like this. :) I've added another assumption, to try and illustrate what happens without complicating things too much.

Comment: @NPE that means assigning an unsigned int to an unsigned char is equivalent to binary anding of the entered value with 0xFF? I mean in this kind of case.

Comment: @SumitGera: In a word, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by "except for the first." but let me see if I can explain what is happening.

`unsigned char` is, I believe, required by the standard to be 1 byte in length. `int` is typically much longer, 4 bytes is typical. Thus when you enter a number >255, it looses all the value above that since all it can hold is one byte and leading 3 bytes of data are lost.